# How to set up a local MySQL user on a Mac on a Zend installation

Tags: mysql, macos, zend-framework, sequelpro

I am trying to set up a user for a localhost database on my Mac.  I created the database in localhost and imported the SQL.  That works fine and I can log into localhost (the local installation of MySQL on my Mac via Sequel Pro) and see it.

I think where things are going awry is in the creation of the user.  I had a pre-existing user with a particular username and password.  I want to use the same user for localhost so that Zend can connect to the database.  So I granted all privileges to the user for the new database schema.  This is the exact same thing I did for the first DB on localhost that I originally created the user for.

After granting all privileges via Sequel Pro to the user for the new schema, I restarted the MySQL server on my Mac (twice).  But Zend won't connect to the database.  It's actually throwing a file not found error, for some strange reason.

I know there's no code here, but I wasn't sure what to post.  I was hoping someone would have some idea about what to do.  I even tried flushing privileges (`FLUSH PRIVILEGES`) on the database twice.  Do I need something more specific than that command?  Anybody have any idea what's going on?  Please don't close this as off-topic or something just because there's no code.  Just move on if my post doesn't suit you.

Comment: Found this for GRANTS for the user:

Comment: GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `XXXX\_spear`.* TO 'XXXX_php'@'localhost' WITH GRANT OPTION                         GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `XXXX\_cerec`.* TO 'XXXX_php'@'localhost' WITH GRANT OPTION

Comment: The first one works, the second one doesn't.  What gives?